# Automatically remove Tomcat logs in Microsoft Azure App Service

Tags: azure, tomcat, configuration, azure-web-app-service, delete-file

I can't find a configuration / tool in the Azure portal to eliminate the logs generated by the Tomcat in order to avoid problems since my storage is full.

From already thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option from the Azure portal directly.

One way I can think of is by creating a copy of tomcat from /usr/local/tomcat to /home/tomcat and then changing tomcat configurations as per: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html

For SpringBoot, tomcat logs are disabled by default.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the very useful information, I will investigate the matter.

Greetings.